# xmllint doesn't work with https - warning: failed to load external entity

Tags: xmllint

`xmllint` does work fine with http://somesite.xml

But it doesn't work with https://somesite.xml

```
xmllint https://somesite.xml
warning: failed to load external entity "https://somesite.xml"
```

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem.

Comment: The same. xmllint doesn't works with DTD on HTTPS.

Comment: If the schema you're using a remote DTD the only workaround I've been able to figure out was to download the DTD locally and replace the schema file with something like: `schemaLocation="file:///tmp/my-path.xsd"`

Comment: "`xmllint` doesn't support HTTPS and probably never will." according to https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/issues/160

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you could use another utility like [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/) or [`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to download the file first, then pipe it to [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html).

```
curl --silent "https://somesite.xml" | xmllint -
```

Notes:

- Use `-` ("hyphen/minus") for `xmllint`'s filename argument to get its XML input from the standard input stream instead of from a file or URL.
- You might want to use `--silent` (`-s`) to suppress `curl` progress/error messages, to prevent those from being parsed by `xmllint`.
- Quotes might be required around the URL if it contains special characters.

This should work for `xmllint`'s XML input over HTTPS, but not sure about a DTD or schema; you might need to download that to a local file first, using a separate `curl` or `wget` command.

Comment: This workaround does not really work for XML schema validation with schemas that have imports using HTTPS in their `schemaLocation`. Only one single schema file can be provided using the `--schema` parameter. The only workaround for that would be to download all imported schemas and modify their `schemaLocation` to relative URLs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly a replacement for `xmllint` as a command-line tool, but the [VS Code XML plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml) supports automatic downloading of [XML schemas](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-xml/blob/main/docs/Validation.md#validation-with-xsd-grammar) via HTTPS.